# Can this Python list comprehension expression be simplified?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
input = "foo ,,bar ,baz,"
tags = [x.strip() for x in input.split(',') if len(x.strip()) > 0]
```

Desired output is obviously a list with no empty strings in it.

The question is in the spirit of micro optimisation; is there a way to not `strip()` the candidate `x` twice, ie once for the test and once for the append?

To rephrase, can you produce a value in the expressions that can be appended to the list without doing the work twice?

Comment: I'm guessing no. Either it gets made for you (if the .strip() caches its result, which I don't think it will) or you'll somehow have to indicate you need an intermediate variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating a new string is always going to be more expensive than scanning it. `x.isspace()` will return after the first not space character is encountered

```
tags = [x.strip() for x in input.split(',') if x and not x.isspace()]
```

Comment: Yep. And it's faster than any of mine. (1.6 seconds compared to 1.95.)

Answer (score 3):

```
text = 'foo ,,bar ,baz,'
```

(I use `text` rather than `input` as `input` is the name of a builtin. Avoid shadowing builtins.)

First of all, `len(x.strip()) > 0` can be written simply (and more efficiently) as `x.strip()`.

```
tags = [x.strip() for x in text.split(',') if x.strip()]
```

If you really wanted to, you could do the strip once only, but I'm not sure if it'd be faster:

```
tags = [x for x in (x.strip() for x in text.split(',')) if x]
```

If you really wanted to, you could even do it functionally...

```
tags = filter(bool, map(lambda x: x.strip(), text.split(',')))
```

Performance figures:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda: [x.strip() for x in text.split(',') if x.strip()])
1.9443869590759277
>>> timeit(lambda: [x for x in (x.strip() for x in text.split(',')) if x])
2.1135239601135254
>>> timeit(lambda: filter(bool, map(lambda x: x.strip(), text.split(','))))
2.52907395362854
```

As you see, the first is fastest.

Comment: OK thanks for the tip there, handy. Does the 'First of all..' imply you can shed some light on the doing-the-work twice bit?

Comment: @markdsievers: it's neater, yes; but if this was a particularly hot code path and so you cared about micro-optimisation, @gnibbler's `if x and not x.isspace()` *is* faster than `if x.strip()`.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly not an application that will set the world afire, so was really just looking for the right balance between performance, duplication and readability. Thanks again for your effort, very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

this works too...

```
 text = "foo ,,bar ,baz,"
 text.replace(',',' ').split()
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work in all cases, e.g. `text = "foo,,bar,,baz"`.  Replace ',' with spaces, i.e. `text.replace(',', ' ').split()` is better.

Comment: This will break on `"foo bar, baz"`, turning it into 3 items instead of 2.